# Ruby -- trying to grab <title>this here</title> even if on multiple lines

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I am grabbing titles using the following method:

```
title = html_response[/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/,1]
```

This does a great job at catching "This is a title" from `<title>This is a title</title>`. However, there are some web pages that open the title tag on one line, print the title on the next line, and then close the title tag.

The Ruby line I presented above doesn't catch titles such as those, so I'm just trying to find a fix for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory don't use regex with HTML sentence.

```
title = html_response[/<title[^>]*>(.*?)<\/title>/m,1]
```

The `m` enables multiline mode.

Answer (score 4):

[This famous stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) explains why it's a bad idea to use regular expressions to parse HTML. A better approach is to use a gem like [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) to parse out the title tags.